# swift web service communication

Tags: ios, web-services, swift, soap

I am trying to build my first swift application and I am having trouble when I am trying to consume the soap web service..
Here is the method:

@IBAction func callWebService(sender: AnyObject) {

```
           var userName:NSString = "abc"
           var password:NSString = "def"


            var soapMsg = "<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://87.106.20.80:8080/axis2/services/app2beeService?wsdl' xmlns:xsd='http://localhost:8080/beeSmartWS' xmlns:soap='http:/bee.myservice.com/userLogin'><soap:Body><userLogin xmlns 'http://87.106.20.80:8080/axis2/services/app2beeService?wsdl/userLogin><:userId>" + userName + "</userId><password>" + password + "</password></userLogin></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>"




                //let soapAction = "http://bee.myservice.com/userLogin"
                //let urlString = "http://bee.myservice.com/"




            let urlString: String = "http://bee.myservice.com/"
            var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlString)!
            //var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
            var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url)
            var msgLength = String(countElements(soapMsg))

                request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
                request.HTTPBody = soapMsg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)
                request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
                request.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
                request.addValue("http://bee.myservice.com/userLogin", forHTTPHeaderField: "Action")



            var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: true)!
            connection.start()
            println(request)

            var response: NSURLResponse?

            var data = NSURLConnection.sendSynchronousRequest(request, returningResponse: &response, error: nil) as NSData?

            if let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse {
                println("error \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
                println(response)
            }

            }
```

}

I am not getting any response when I send across this request

Web service details:
Web service Type: Axis2 (Java and SOAP based)
Web service WSDL link: http://87.106.20.80:8080/axis2/services/app2beeService?wsdl Target Namespace: http://bee.myservice.com
SOAP Action: Add /userLogin to target namespace

Comment: Are you getting an error code? Side note: NSURLSession is preferable to the older NSURLConnection. You don't need to use Alamofire but you should use NSURLSession.

Comment: I get an http error code 200 when I use the url of the webservice running on my local machine (http://localhost:8080/beeSmartWS/)  but the other url (target namespace) returns an error code 500

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was an issue with the soap message, after some trial and error I figured out the right message.

```html
var is_SoapMessage: String = "
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\ "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:ns=\ "url\">
  <soapenv:Header/>
  <soapenv:Body>
    <ns:userLogin>
      <ns:userID>username</ns:userID>
      <ns:password>password</ns:password>
    </ns:userLogin>
  </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to use Alamofire (https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire).
Your code would look like:

```
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "http://bee.myservice.com"))
let msgLength = String(countElements(soapMsg))
let data = soapMsg.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: false)

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.addValue("text/xml; charset=utf-8", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
request.addValue(msgLength, forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Length")
request.addValue("http://bee.myservice.com/userLogin", forHTTPHeaderField: "Action")

Alamofire.upload( request, data )
    .response { (request, response, data, error) in
        // do stuff here
    }
```

Alamofire is being used by a lot of people, and operations are performed asynchronously as they should be (but very easily thanks to closures).

Comment: I tried doing it..but I could not figure out how to add the Alamofire library into my already existing project

Comment: There're a couple of ways to do it. Probably the easiest one is just downloading it and then adding Alamofire.swift to your project (that's the only way if your app must work with iOS 7). If you do it that way you will have to just call upload instead of Alamofire.upload